# ContentObserver onChange() is not being called.

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, contentobserver

I have a `ContentProvider`.  My `update` method in my content provider is :

```
       @Override
   public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
      int count = 0;
      switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)){
      case CONTACT:
         count = db.update(CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME, values, 
                 selection, selectionArgs);
         break;
      case CONTACT_ID:
         count = db.update(CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME, values, _ID + 
                 " = " + uri.getPathSegments().get(1) + 
                 (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ? " AND (" +
                 selection + ')' : ""), selectionArgs);
         break;
      default: 
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri );
      }
      getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
      return count;
   }
```

Then I am implementing a `ContentObserver`. 
**`MYContentObserver`**

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public class MyObserver extends ContentObserver {        
        public MyObserver(Handler handler) {
            super(handler);            
        }
        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            List<Contact> newData;
            if(CONTACT_TYPE == VOIP_CONTACTS){
                newData = ContactsManager.getVoipContacts(getActivity());
            }else{
                newData = ContactsManager.getAllContacts(getActivity());
            }
            customAdapter.contacts().clear();
            customAdapter.contacts().addAll(newData);
            customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

And I am regsitering it in my onCreate like :

```
getActivity().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(MyContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, true, myObserver);
```

And in my `onOptionItemSelected`, on click of one of the item, m updating like :

```
getActivity().getContentResolver().update(ContactsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, values, where, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example you have given you are not registering and updating the same URI.

You are registering to listen for changes on the `MyContentProvider.CONTENT_URI` uri, but you are making changes on the `ContactsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI` uri.

Comment: Its just by chance here. in my code, its exactly the same.